# How to mock a module for only one test file with Jest?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

I am using **Jest** and I want to mock some functions from another module (let's call it `dependency`).

I was able to mock `dependency` **globally**, putting it inside a `__mocks__` folder inside my `__tests__` folder.

Unfortunately, I need the actual `dependecy` for all the other tests. So, how can I specify that I want to require the mocked `dependecy` only when required in my `file1.js`, but not in all other files?

PS: I could create a `__mocks__` folder inside my `file1.js` folder, but this file is in the root, so when `dependency` is required by any file it will be picked up from the `__mocks__`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use [`jest.mock`](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/jest-object.html#jestmockmodulename-factory-options):

```
jest.mock('path/to/dependency', () => 'someMockValue')
```

Note that the path is relative to the test file, not to the file you want test.